# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS doesn't wake up from suspend, furthermore, no "Hibernate" button

Tags: 16.04, sound, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I have an Asus notebook ([E200HA](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-Vivobook-E200HA/))

When I suspend the system, the screen shuts down but the computer activity light stays on, I pressed all the button I could but no way to power on the screen back. I also have no hibernate button.

Furthermore I have no soundcard detected by Ubuntu, that's no big deal I just bought an external one but if you have a solution I'll be thankful.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If yours is using the Cherry Trail Atom SOC, then according to [this](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/E200HA), Intel has not created (or will not support) Linux drivers. This means that currently you will have issues with:

- Hibernation
- Suspension (link has a suggestion to disable accidental suspensions)
- WiFi (possibly fixable - see link)
- Keyboard's Hotkeys
- Integrated Audio